# Facebook App URL Issue

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-fbml

I have an FBML app and a strange thing keeps happening.

If I go to http://apps.facebook.com/**myapp/page2.php**

I just get redirected to http://apps.facebook.com/**myapp/index.php**

It always goes back to index.php even though I specified page2.php and it is in the URL. This doesn't happen to my iframe apps.

Does anybody know why it's behaving this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like making the canvas callback URL http://WWW.example.com rather than just http://example.com fixed the problem.

But why???

Answer (score 1):

htaccess rewrites